# jQuery handle multiple events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Wijmo SpreadJS. I need to fire events, when the cell data (or anything in the spreadsheet) changes. [From the documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadHClientUG/webframe.html#Spread~%24.wijmo.wijspread.Events.html) I found these two:

- CellChanged - triggered when data in any cell changes
- RangeChanged - triggered when a cell data is deleted

Therefore, I need to trigger the same function for both events, but it isn't working:

```
function (){
    var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");

    spread.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.RangeChanged $.wijmo.wijspread.Events.CellChanged, function (sender, args) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    /// code here
                   });  
        },0);
    });
};
```

I get no error, but none of these two events is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the types of those events are strings, you could do this:

```
spread.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.RangeChanged + ' ' + $.wijmo.wijspread.Events.CellChanged, function (sender, args) {
```

If they aren't strings, and you can't get a string to represent the event, you probably need to do this:

```
function changeHandler(sender, args) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            /// code here
        });  
    },0);
}

spread
    .bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.RangeChanged, changeHandler)
    .bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.CellChanged, changeHandler);
```

Comment: The 1st approach worked fine, I guess the event types are strings then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jaso P Sorry if ask for your help here, but I really need a hand here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403503/jquery-how-to-split-table-cell-into-a-different-number-of-rows-from-column-to-co  Again, I do apologize for commenting on someone else's question

Answer (score 0):

[$.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) expects a string of events. The parameter value you're trying to pass:

```
$.wijmo.wijspread.Events.RangeChanged $.wijmo.wijspread.Events.CellChanged
```

isn't valid JS syntax.

Try

```
function (){
    var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");
    var myEventHandler = function (sender, args) {
        // code to handle events
    }

    spread.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.RangeChanged, myEventHandler);
    spread.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.CellChanged, myEventHandler);
};
```

or

```
function (){
    var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");
    var myEventHandler = function (sender, args) {
        // code to handle events
    }

    var eventsToBind = $.wijmo.wijspread.Events.CellChanged + " " + $.wijmo.wijspread.Events.RangeChanged;
    spread.bind(eventsToBind, myEventHandler);
};
```